# Only Last Player Is Visible In Game

Tags: javascript, html, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer game with HTML, and I can't figure out how to fix the problem with only 1 player being shown. Here's the relevant code:

```
socket.on('newpos', function(data){
            var transform = ctx.getTransform();
            var camX, camY;
            for(var i = 0 ; i < data.player.length; i++){
              ctx.translate(camX, camY);
              ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
              ctx.clearRect(0,0,10000,10000); 
              ctx.setTransform(transform);
              ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 10000,10000); 
              ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

              if(ID == data.player[i].id){ 
                 camX = -data.player[i].x + canvas.width / 2;
                 camY = -data.player[i].y + canvas.height / 2;
              }
              ctx.translate(camX,camY);
              ctx.drawImage(img, (data.player[i].x),(data.player[i].y),32,32);
});
```

The code here loops through all the players on the server. It draws the different player's perspectives, but only the last player that joined is visible.
I've tried changing the transforms in different places and everything else I could think of, not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you clear the entire canvas at every iteration, so only the last is visible

Take out/change the position of

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,10000,10000)
```

Also the above code as of now should give an error since it appears the closing bracket of the for loop is missing